fill the Formula field from one filed if the other is null
I have a formula field in Opportunity, which should fetch the value from one field of Contact object if it's an individual OR fetch value from one field of Account if it's an Organization. Below is the formula I use.

IF(ISBLANK(Vendor__c),IF (ISBLANK(VendorAccount__c), '',
TEXT(VendorAccount__r.State__c)), TEXT(Vendor__r.State__c))

However, Now I should fetch a value from Vendor__r.ActiveState or VendorAccount__r.ActiveState if all the fields in the above formula are null.

You can extend your existing formula to include an additional check for the ActiveState fields.
IF( ISBLANK(Vendor__c), 
        IF( ISBLANK(VendorAccount__c),
                IF( ISBLANK(Vendor__r.State__c) && ISBLANK(VendorAccount__r.State__c),
                        IF( ISBLANK(Vendor__r.ActiveState),
                        TEXT(VendorAccount__r.ActiveState),
                        TEXT(Vendor__r.ActiveState)
                        ),
                TEXT(VendorAccount__r.State__c)
                ),
        TEXT(VendorAccount__r.State__c)
        ),
        IF( ISBLANK(Vendor__r.State__c),
                IF( ISBLANK(Vendor__r.ActiveState),
                        TEXT(VendorAccount__r.ActiveState),
                        TEXT(Vendor__r.ActiveState)
                ),
        TEXT(Vendor__r.State__c)
        )
)

This formula checks the following:

If Vendor__c is blank, it checks VendorAccount__c.
If VendorAccount__c is also blank, it checks if both Vendor__r.State__c and VendorAccount__r.State__c are blank.
If both state fields are blank, it then checks Vendor__r.ActiveState and VendorAccount__r.ActiveState.
If Vendor__r.State__c is not blank, it returns that value.
If Vendor__c is not blank, it checks Vendor__r.State__c and then Vendor__r.ActiveState.

